# reservation form in php

Tags: php, forms

It ia a reservation form contains 6 fields, Name, Phone, Checkin date, Checkout date, Adults , Rooms ... after entering details we submit it , after submiting the details it comes to my email id what i specifies in contact.php,, but i didnt get the details whrn i click on submit button,,but it doesnot shows any error message ...can u check it and give me the correct code..or give me the new html with php code for hotel reservation form with my requirements

```
<?php 

$mailto = 'websitemail@gmail.com' ; 
$subject = "Your Contact Form" ; 
$thankyouurl = "http://www.wesite.com/thankyou.html" ; 
$formurl = "http://www.website.com/index.html" ; 
$errorurl = "http://www.website.com/error.html" ; 

$uself = 0; 
$use_sendmailfrom = 0; 
$use_webmaster_email_for_from = 0; 
$use_utf8 = 1; 
$headersep = (!isset( $uself ) || ($uself == 0)) ? "\r\n" : "\n" ; 
$content_type = (!isset( $use_utf8 ) || ($use_utf8 == 0)) ? 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"' : 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' ; 
if (isset( $use_sendmailfrom ) && $use_sendmailfrom) { 

ini_set( 'sendmail_from', $mailto ); 
} 
$firstname = addslashes($_POST['firstname']) ; 
$phone = addslashes($_POST['phone']) ; 
$checkin = addslashes($_POST['checkin']) ; 
$checkout = addslashes($_POST['checkout']) ; 
$adults = addslashes($_POST['adults']) ; 
$rooms = addslashes($_POST['rooms']) ; 

$http_referrer = getenv( "HTTP_REFERER" ); 

if (!isset($_POST['email'])) { 

header( "Location: $formurl" ); 

exit ; 
} 


$valid_firstname = (!empty($firstname)) ? true : false; 
$valid_phone = (!empty($phone)) ? true : false; 
$valid_checkin = (!empty($checkin)) ? true : false; 
$valid_checkout = (!empty($checkout)) ? true : false; 
$valid_adults = (!empty($adults)) ? true : false; 
$valid_rooms = (!empty($rooms)) ? true : false; 

$fromemail = (!isset( $use_webmaster_email_for_from ) || ($use_webmaster_email_for_from == 0)) ? $email : $mailto ; 

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST); 
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) { 
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) { 
            unset($process[$key][$k]); 
            if (is_array($v)) { 
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v; 
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)]; 
            } else { 
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    unset($process); 
} 

$messageproper = 

"This message was sent from:\n" . 

"$http_referrer\n" . 

"------------------------------------------------------------\n" . 

"First Name: $firstname\n" . 
"Phone: $Phone\n" . 
"Check In: $checkin\n" . 
"Check Out: $checkout\n" . 
"Adults: $adults\n" . 
"Number of Rooms: $rooms\n" . 


 "------------------------------------------------------------\n" ; 

$headers = "From: \"$firstname\" <$fromemail>" . $headersep . "Reply-To: \"$firstname\" <$email>" . $headersep . "X-Mailer: chfeedback.php 2.15.0" . $headersep . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $headersep . $content_type ; 

if ($valid_firstname && $valid_phone && $valid_checkin && $valid_checkout && $valid_adults && $valid_rooms) { 
mail( $mailto, $subject, $messageproper, $headers ); 
} 

else { 
header( "Location: $errorurl" ); 
exit ; 
} 

header( "Location: $thankyouurl" ); 
exit ;
?>


HTML CODE::

<div class="contactform">enter code here
<span style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: Verdana; color: #000000;">

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="contact.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

<fieldset><legend><span style="font-size: 12px;">&nbsp;CONTACT DETAILS&nbsp;</span></legend>
 <label for="firstname" class="left">First name:</label>
<font color="#FF0000">*</font><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="field" value="" maxlength="35" tabindex="1" /><br /><br />

<label for="phone" class="left">Phone:</label>
<font color="#FF0000">*</font><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="field" value="" maxlength="10" tabindex="2" /><br /><br />

<label for="checkin" class="left">Check In:</label>
<font color="#FF0000">*</font><input type="text" class="datepicker" tabindex="3" /><br /><br />


<label for="checkout" class="left">Check Out:</label>
<font color="#FF0000">*</font><input type="text" class="datepicker" tabindex="4" /><br /><br />

<label for="adults" class="left">Persons:</label>
<font color="#FF0000">*</font><input type="text" name="adults" id="adults" class="field" value="" maxlength="45" tabindex="5" /><br /><br />

<label for="rooms" class="left">Number of Rooms:</label>
<font color="#FF0000">*</font><input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="field" value="" maxlength="35" tabindex="6" /><br /><br />

</fieldset>

<input type="reset" name="clear" id="clear" class="button" value="Clear" tabindex="7" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Send" tabindex="8" /><br /><br />

</fieldset>
</form>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code at the top of your PHP file to display errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If errors are still not being displayed go into your `php.ini` file and set `Display_Errors = On`

Comment: yah it shows an error... 

Undefined index: checkin in /home/prakashp/public_html/contact.php on line 24

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/prakashp/public_html/contact.php:24) in /home/prakashp/public_html/contact.php on line 33

Comment: OK the line 24 is not important, but the problem you are having is you are trying to redirect the user with `header( "Location: $url" );` after you are printing things to the browser. You cannot do that. Either wrap your entire script in `ob_start();` and `ob_end_flush();` or code it differently so you are not printing anything to the browser (even HTML tags) before trying to redirect.

Comment: Actually i also dont know how to rectify errors, Can u please provide HTML and php code for my requirement.

Comment: in php form date picker is not working